# Shift bezier curve as a whole in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, bezier

Is there an easy way to shift a bezier curve as a whole, e.g. 2cm in x-direction,1 cm in y-direction without changing the control points?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (2,-1) .. (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The xshift- and yshift-key don't seem to be usable for that. Thank you

**Edit:** As Guilherme pointed out the *shift* property works well:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (2,-1) .. (3,0);
  \draw[shift={(2cm,1cm)}] (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (2,-1) .. (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However it doesn't work when you define coordinates for the curve beforehand:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A2) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (A3) at (2,-1);
    \coordinate (A4) at (3,0);

    \draw (A1) .. controls (A2) and (A3) .. (A4);
    \draw[shift={(2cm,1cm)}] (A1) .. controls (A2) and (A3) .. (A4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The second curve then doesn't move from its original position.

Comment: `\draw[shift={(2cm,1cm)}] (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (2,-1) .. (3,0);` should work

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Well, why not? Do you get an error?? It works for me. Just consider that `tikz` automatically clips the bouding box, so you need to add something on `(0,0)` otherwise the drawing will get clipped and it will look like the curve wasn't shifted, when it actually was... Try putting `\path (0,0);` somewhere inside the picture.

Comment: Sorry, the answer you posted works well. However it doesn't seem to work if you previously define coordinates for the curve (see my edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coordinates are not shifted, they are fixed (which is a good thing, normally that's what we want). You can do this in two ways: `transform canvas={shift={(2cm,1cm)}}` instead of just `shift`.

Or you can shift all coordinates: `c/.style={shift={(2cm,1cm)}}` then:

```
\draw[shift={(2cm,1cm)}] ([c]A1) .. controls ([c]A2) and ([c]A3) .. ([c]A4);
```

Both should work and the second way should be prefferd, messing with coordinate system transformations can lead to unexpected result (unexpected if you don't know what the tool does...).

Answer (score 1):

Another idea (which could or could not be appropiate to your case, I don't know) is to define the required shape as a `pic`. Inside the `pic` you can use named coordinates to draw your shape, and then, when the `pic` is used as part of your drawing it can be easily shifted, scaled or rotated:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}

\tikzset{
mybezier/.pic = {
    \coordinate (A1) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (A2) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (A3) at (2,-1);
    \coordinate (A4) at (3,0);
    \draw (A1) .. controls (A2) and (A3) .. (A4);
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) pic {mybezier};
\path (2,1) pic {mybezier};
\path (0,-1) pic[red, rotate=-30, scale=1.5] {mybezier};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: Result]